# How to add radio buttons from different fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have 5 question. Each fragment has a question with 4 radio buttons. Each radio button has a tag between 1-4. In the 5 fragment it has a submit button and all the radio buttons should add up and display on a total on a new activity. However, whenever I click submit the total number is always 5 (the fragments 1-4 don't add up. What do I need to add on fragments 1-4 so the values can add and display on total.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaowT.jpg)

```java
package com.example.act.Fragments;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.act.R;
import com.example.act.ResultActivity;

public class Q5Fragment extends Fragment {

    private RadioGroup radioGroup;
    private Button btnSubmit;
    private int total = 0; // Initialize total to 0

    public Q5Fragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_q5, container, false);

        radioGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        btnSubmit = view.findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
                    if (radioButton.isChecked()) {
                        int selectedValue = Integer.parseInt(radioButton.getTag().toString());
                        total += selectedValue;
                    }
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ResultActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("totalValue", total);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public void receiveFragmentValue(int selectedValue) {
        total += selectedValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only one RadioButton can be checked.   So what is it that you want to 'add up' and 'display'?

Comment: @blackapps if I understood correctly, OP wants to sum the tag values of each selected RadioButton

Comment: @marcinj, yes but only one can be checked/selected so there is nothing to sum or add.

Comment: Sum = tags of selected radiobuttons from all fragments

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make your `Q5Fragment` `btnSubmit` handler call some method in `Activity` derived class which will do the summing and then opening result activity. So your submit handler would look something like:

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((QuestionAware)getActivity()).submitQuestions();
            }
        });
```

This requires you to declare an Inteface:

```
 interface QuestionAware {
   void submitQuestions();
 }
```

and then implement it in your Activity which holds your fragments.

Now, in `submitQuestions` of your Activtiy you will get all the values from your fragments. To do it, make each fragment have a method returning its value:

```
public int getSelectedValue() {
    int selectedValue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (radioButton.isChecked()) {
            selectedValue = Integer.parseInt(radioButton.getTag().toString());
        }
    }
    return selectedValue;
}
```

Then in `submitQuestions` summ those values and open new activity:

```
int total = fragment1.getSelectedValue() + fragment2.getSelectedValue() + fragment3.getSelectedValue() + fragment4.getSelectedValue() + fragment5.getSelectedValue();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, ResultActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("totalValue", total);
startActivity(intent);
```